# Installing Bazel Release 0.1.2 on a Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, bazel

I'm installing tensorflow on a Mac OS X 10.11.12 with Xcode 7.2 and JDK 8 already installed.

I'm following the instructions here - http://bazel.io/docs/install.html

```
$ chmod +x install-_version-os.sh_
$ ./install-version-os.sh --user
```

And have downloaded the file `bazel-0.1.2-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh`

how do I type the aforementioned instructions, given the filename for the downloaded file?

Thanks.

George

Answer (score 5):

Simply open a terminal, go to the directory where you downloaded the file using the cd command and execute the instructions.

```
chmod +x bazel-0.1.2-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.1.2-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
```